# 1D FEM for nonlinear diffusion coefficient

Tags: linear-algebra, finite-element, parabolic-pde, linear-system

I want to solve with **linear finite elements** the equation $$\partial_t u = \partial_{x}(a(u)\partial_xu)$$
in the domain $t \in [0,1]$ and $x \in [-L,L]$. Here $a(u)$ is just a function of $u$.

Applying the weak formulation with $u(t,x)=\sum_{j} u_j(t) \varphi_j(x)$, I obtain $$\partial_t u_j(t) \int_{-L}^{L}\varphi_i(x)\varphi_j(x)dx = - \int_{-L}^{L} a\Bigl( \sum_j u_j(t) \varphi_j(x) \Bigr) \Bigl(  \sum_k u_k(t) \varphi_k^{'}(x) \Bigr)  \varphi_{i}^{'}(x)dx$$

- The l.h.s is no problem because it is $M \dot{U}(t)$, where $(M)_{ij}=\int_{-L}^{L} \varphi_i(x) \varphi_j(x)dx$ and $U(t)=[u(x_1,t),\ldots,u(x_N,t)]^{T}$
- My **big problem** is on the r.h.s. I don't know how to handle that double summation so that I have a function of $U(t)$, because I obtain a tensor $B_{ijk}=\int_{-L}^{L} \varphi_i \varphi_j \varphi_k^{'}$ ( [there has already been a question about this](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/27943/bubnov-galerkin-method-in-1d-how-to-handle-convective-type-nonlinearity?rq=1)) but I can't understand how to solve this in practice on a computer.

As described in the linked question, I will obtain $$M \dot{U} = (BU)U$$ but this seems just formal to me, because of that tensor. Any help is highly appreciated

---

**EDIT after knl answer**:

@knl I have a question about the root-finding step:

After time discretization, I have $u_n(x)$, therefore the problem is still continuous in space. From the the scalar prodcut $$ (\delta^{-1} u_{k,n}, v) + (a(u_{k-1,n}) \partial_x u_{k,n}, \partial_x v) = (\delta^{-1}u_{n-1}, v) $$ I want to find how to compute the solution by fix point iteration

Let $A$ the usual "stiffness matrix" and $M$ the "mass matrix":

$$\delta^{-1} M u_k^n + a(u_{k-1}^n) A u_k^n = \delta^{-1}M u^{n-1}$$ where $u_k^{n}$  is the coefficients vector and $k$ is the index referring to the fix-point iteration.

Therefore, I iteratively find $u_k^n$ by solving the linear systems $$(\delta^{-1} M + a(u_{k-1}^n) A)u_k^n = \delta^{-1} M u^{n-1}$$

What I obtain after integration up to time $t=1$ is
[image]

which is slightly different from yours. I can't understand if there's an error in my code, because the fixed point iterations seem to work.

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    
    
    def stiffassembly(M):
        x = np.linspace(0,1,M+1)
        diag = np.zeros(M-1) #x_1,...,x_M-1 (M-1)
        subd = np.zeros(M-2) 
        supr = np.zeros(M-2)
        h = np.diff(x)
        for i in range(1,M):
            diag[i-1] = 1/h[i-1] +1/h[i]
    
        for k in range(1,M-1):
            supr[k-1] = -1/h[k]
            subd[k-1] = -1/h[k]
    
        A = np.diag(subd,-1) + np.diag(diag,0) + np.diag(supr,+1)
        return A
    
    
    def massmatrix(N):
        x = np.linspace(0,1,N+1)
        diag = np.zeros(N-1) #x_1,...,x_M-1 (M-1)
        subd = np.zeros(N-2) 
        supr = np.zeros(N-2)
        h = np.diff(x)
        for i in range(1,N):
            diag[i-1] = (h[i-1] + h[i])/3
    
        for k in range(1,N-1):
            supr[k-1] = h[k]/6
            subd[k-1] = h[k-1]/6
    
        M = np.diag(subd,-1) + np.diag(diag,0) + np.diag(supr,+1)
        return M
    
    
    def inidata(x):
        return np.sin(np.pi*x)
    
    
    
    a = lambda w: (1. * w) ** 2
    
    
    M = 50
    x = np.linspace(0,1,M+1)
    delta = 0.001
    odx = 1.0/delta
    tol = 1e-14
    uprev = inidata(x[1:-1])
    ts = 1000 #integration up to t=1.0
    for n in range(ts):
        print('iteration',str(n))
        u = uprev.copy()
        uold = u.copy() + 1
        it = 0
        while (np.linalg.norm(u-uold)>tol):
            uold=u.copy()   
            u = np.linalg.solve(odx*massmatrix(M) + np.diag(a(u))@stiffassembly(M), odx*massmatrix(M)@uprev)
            errnrm = np.linalg.norm(u-uold)
            print(errnrm)
        uprev = u.copy()
        
    
    plt.plot(x,np.r_[0,u,0],'g-o',)
```

---

**EDIT (last one)**
Actually what I have before is wrong, before I do not update the matrix in the fix point iteration. Fixing this, i.e. changing the function `stiffassembly`, i obtain the following, which is right, as it has been "three"-checked (with @knl fem solver, with a finite difference approach, and with mathematica):

[image]

Comment: @knl I don't know how to handle that tensor for a practical implementation

Comment: I think that your edit should be an answer.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You would need to linearize the problem. I prefer to do it before discretization but it's possible to do also after discretization. (I'm a bit skeptical of linearization after discretization because I have never looked into the details. In general, discretization and linearization steps do not commute.)

In the following I assume that the equation is actually $\partial_t u = \partial_x(a(u) \partial_x u)$ and that you have the boundary condition $u=0$.

The weak form is
$$(\partial_t u, v) = -(a(u) \partial_x u, \partial_x v).$$
I prefer to first do the time discretization so that you see the structure of the resulting problem. E.g., implicit Euler method leads to
$$(\delta^{-1}(u_n - u_{n-1}), v) = -(a(u_n) \partial_x u_n, \partial_x v),$$
or, equivalently,
$$(\delta^{-1} u_n, v) + (a(u_n) \partial_x u_n, \partial_x v) = (\delta^{-1}u_{n-1}, v),$$
where $n$ runs over the time steps and $\delta > 0$ is the size of the step.
The equation is still nonlinear in $u_n$ and you must linearize.
One option is to do a fixed-point iteration (inside each time step $n$) by repeatedly finding $u_{k,n}$ from
$$(\delta^{-1} u_{k,n}, v) + (a(u_{k-1,n}) \partial_x u_{k,n}, \partial_x v) = (\delta^{-1}u_{n-1}, v),$$
where $k$ runs over the linearization steps and $u_{k-1,n}$ is the function from the previous iteration. Notice how you now have two iterations: one for time discretization and one for linearization.

I made an example case with $u(x) = \sin(\pi x)$ and solved it using the code I know the best (i.e. my own, you can install it in Python using `pip install scikit-fem==2.0.0` if you want to run it):

```py
from skfem import *
from skfem.helpers import *
from skfem.visuals.matplotlib import *
import numpy as np

m = MeshLine(); m.refine(5)
basis = InteriorBasis(m, ElementLineP2())
a = lambda w: (1. * w) ** 2
bilinf_stiffness = BilinearForm(lambda u, v, w: a(w['u_prev']) * dot(grad(u), grad(v)))
delta = 0.01
M = BilinearForm(lambda u, v, w: 1. / delta * u * v).assemble(basis)
load = LinearForm(lambda v, w: 1. / delta * w['u_prev'] * v)

u = project(lambda x: np.sin(np.pi * x[0]), basis_to=basis)
plot(basis, u)
for n in range(100): # 100 time steps 
    b = load.assemble(basis, u_prev=basis.interpolate(u))
    for k in range(250): # 250 linearization loops
        A = bilinf_stiffness.assemble(basis, u_prev=basis.interpolate(u))
        u = solve(*condense(A + M, b, D=m.boundary_nodes()))
    print("iteration {}".format(n))
plot(basis, u)
show()
```

This gives the following two pictures (initial condition and the result at $t=1$):
[image: Initial field]
[image: Solution at t=1]

There are obviously lots of alternative ways of doing this, but this should give you the general idea.

Comment: Now it's clear. Just to conclude, I've never done such an assembly. So, basically, when I evaluate at integration points, $a(u_{k-1,n}) $ is a vector with components, say $\vec{a}$. Then, the integral becomes $$\int_0^1 \sum_j a_j \phi_j \sum_j u_j \phi _j^{'} \phi_i^{i} dx$$ right? Or is is just $$\int_0^1 \sum_j a_j \phi_j  \phi _j^{'} \phi_i^{'} dx$$

Comment: Looking at your code, it seems that you are not using integration points at all. Instead you have already evaluated the integrals analytically with the assumption that $A_{ij} = \int_0^1 \phi_j^\prime(x) \phi_i^\prime(x) dx$. Now that you have $A_{ij} = \int_0^1 b(x) \phi_j^\prime(x) \phi_i^\prime(x) dx$ (where $b(x) = a(u_{k-1,n}(x))$) this becomes impossible unless you make further assumptions, e.g., set $b(x)$ to the mean of $a(u_{k-1,n}(x))$ over each element. This seems to be a common way to obtain analytical integrals, and usually works quite well if $b(x)$ is smooth enough.

Comment: Let me add that I think it might be possible to integrate analytically also when $b(x)$ is piecewise-linear. Denote by $b_i$ the value of $b(x)$ at $i$'th node $x_i$ which corresponds to $\phi_i$. Then you would have, e.g., $\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x-x_i}{x_{i+1}-x_i}b_i + \frac{x_i-x}{x_{i+1}-x_i} b_{i+1}\right) \phi_i^\prime \phi_{i+1}^\prime dx$ for the off-diagonals which I think can be integrated analytically. Nevertheless, most of the generic finite element codes are usually implemented with the help of numerical integration.

Comment: thanks, now I understood how to move. By the wayI was writing explicitely the integrals for the assembly, I think that your integral should be $$\int_0^1 \left(\frac{x_{i+1}-x}{x_{i+1}-x_i}b_i + \frac{x-x_i}{x_{i+1}-x_i} b_{i+1}\right) \phi_i^\prime \phi_{i+1}^\prime dx$$, right?

Comment: Oh yes, sorry, you're correct. Basically, you interpolate linearly between those two values, $b_i$ and $b_{i+1}$, inside the element.

Comment: Comments are not for extended discussion; this conversation has been [moved to chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113196/discussion-on-answer-by-knl-1d-fem-for-nonlinear-diffusion-coefficient). I left some of the comments which in my opinion are more relevant than others using my own judgment (reason: chat is not too good with MathJax)

Comment: @knl I asked a question, following the approach you proposed above, for a problem pretty similar to the one above
 https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35967/finite-element-1d-for-steady-state-non-linear-problem

Answer (score 0):

The equation you have is
$$
M \dot U = B(U) U
$$
where $B$ is a matrix which depends on the solution and is given by
$$
B_{ij} = \int a(u_h) \phi_i' \phi_j' dx
$$

Comment: could you expand a bit your answer? It's not clear to me how you got the $B_{ij}$, i.e. a matrix and not a tensor, as Wolfgang wrote in the linked question

Comment: Also, what is, explicitely, $a(u_h)$?

Comment: You must know the function $a(u)$. So $a(u_h)$ just means evaluate it at the numerical solution.

Comment: My bad, sorry! I have a question about that term. When I discretize, $a(u_h)$ is a vector. So I have, after calling $A$ the matrix with $(A)_{ij} = \int \phi_i' \phi_j' dx$ 

$$\vec{a} A$$ where the multiplication is entrywise. Should this be written in a program as $\text{diag(a(uh)) * A$?

Comment: Its a nonlinear problem. You have to integrate with $a(u_h)$ inside the integral. The matrix depends on the solution, so you have to recompute it every time $u_h$ changes.

Comment: Oh, I see now. I'm having difficulties to understand how it's done the $(i,j)$ entry of the matrix: is it this one $$\int a(\sum_j u_k \phi_k) \phi_i{'} \phi_j{'}$$ ?

I've never seen such an assembly, so I don't know how to move