# Finite element (1D) for steady state non-linear problem

Tags: finite-element, boundary-conditions, numerics, advection-diffusion

I need to solve with linear finite elements the equation  $$\frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Bigl(\text{sgn}(x) u \Big) +\frac{\partial}{\partial x} \Bigl[ \sqrt{u} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x} \Bigr] =0$$

with boundary conditions $u(-L)=u(L)=0$ where $L=6$

(It's the steady state version of the equation described here: [Non-Linear advection diffusion with nondifferetiable advection term](https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35955/non-linear-advection-diffusion-with-nondifferetiable-advection-term))

---

I take $v \in H_0^1(-L,L)$ and after the usual steps I obtain $$- \int u(x) \text{sgn}(x) v'  dx - \int \sqrt{u} u' v' dx = 0$$

Then, using linear finite elements:
$$- \int \sum_{j} u_j \phi_j(x) \phi_i'(x) \text{sgn}(x)dx - \int \Bigl( \sum_k \sqrt{u_k \phi_k}  \Bigr) \sum_j u_j \phi_j' \phi_i' dx = 0$$

which leads to the **non-linear system** (setting $U=[u_0,\ldots,u_N]$)

$$-C U -A(U) U =$$

where $(C)_{ij} = \int \sum_{j} u_j \phi_j(x) \phi_i'(x) \text{sgn}(x)dx $

and $\Bigl(A(U)\Bigr)_{ij} =\int \Bigl( \sum_k \sqrt{u_k \phi_k} \Bigr) \sum_j u_j \phi_j' \phi_i' dx$

Now, I want to solve this non-linear equation with **fix-point iterations**, so I set $$CU^{k+1} = -A(U^k)U^k$$ and solve iteratively those linear systems.

**The problem:** unfortunately, the fix-point iteration gives me `NaN` and I can't find the solution. Is it because the problem is ill-posed, or did I do something wrong with my idea of fixpoint iterations?

---

After @cos_theta's comment, I modified my code with the right weak formulation, but still the solution can't be found. Basically, I made two functions, one where I assemble the matrix $A(U)$, and the other one where I assemble the matrix $C$. Then I have the fixed-point iteration loop.

In particular, the matrix $A(U)$ corresponds to $$\int \sqrt{ \sum_k u_k \phi_k } \sum_j u_j \phi_j' \phi_i' dx = 0$$

so it's tridiagonal and, for instance, the diagonal entry is $$\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \sqrt{u_{i-1}}\sqrt{\phi_{i-1}} \frac{1}{h^2}dx + \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \sqrt{u_{i+1}} \sqrt{\phi_{i+1}} \frac{1}{h^2}dx + \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_{i+1}} \sqrt{u_i} \sqrt{\phi_i} \frac{1}{h^2} dx $$

where the values $\sqrt{u_{i-1}}$, $\sqrt{u_i}$, $\sqrt{u_{i+1}}$ are given by the previous iteration.

For the matrix $C$, I have that $$C_{ii}= \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \frac{1}{h} \phi_i \text{sgn}(x) dx + \int_{x_i}^{x_{i+1}} \frac{-1}{h} \phi_i  \text{sgn}(x)dx$$ If the interval does not contain $x=0$, then  $C_{ii}=0$. Otherwise, as shown in the linked answer, the entry that contains $x=0$ is $-1$. So the resulting matrix is like this

$$C = \begin{pmatrix}0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 & 0 \\  -\frac{1}{2} & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & 0 \\  0 & -\frac{1}{2} & -1 & -\frac{1}{2} & 0 \\  0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0 & -\frac{1}{2} \\  0 & 0 & 0 & \frac{1}{2} & 0\end{pmatrix}$$

```py
    import numpy as np
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    import scipy.integrate as integrate
    
    L = 6
    def stiffassembly(a,M):
        # a is the vector containg the previous solution. It's long M+1, it takes also boundary values in order to assemble the matrix
        x = np.linspace(-L,L,M+1)
        diag = np.zeros(M-1) #x_1,...,x_M-1 (M-1)
        supr = np.zeros(M-2)
        h = x[1]-x[0]
        c = 1.0/(h**2)
        for i in range(1,M):
            diag[i-1] = a[i-1]*c*integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sqrt((x[i]-t)/h),x[i-1],x[i])[0] + a[i+1]*c*integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sqrt((t-x[i])/h),x[i],x[i+1])[0] + a[i]*( integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sqrt((t-x[i-1])/h),x[i-1],x[i])[0] + integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sqrt((x[i+1]-t)/h),x[i],x[i+1])[0] )
            
    
        for k in range(1,M-1):
            supr[k-1] = a[k]*(-c)*integrate.quad(lambda t:np.sqrt((x[k+1]-t)/h),x[k],x[k+1])[0] + a[k+1]*(-c)*integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sqrt((t - x[k])/h),x[k],x[k+1])[0]
    
        A = np.diag(supr,-1) + np.diag(diag,0) + np.diag(supr,+1)
        return A
    
    
    def Cmatrix(M):
        x = np.linspace(-L,L,M+1)
        diag = np.zeros(M-1)
        subd = np.zeros(M-2)
        supr = np.zeros(M-2)
        h = x[1]-x[0]
        c = 1.0/(h**2)
        for i in range(1,M): 
            diag[i-1] = c*integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sign(t)*(t-x[i-1]),x[i-1],x[i])[0] - c*integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sign(t)*(x[i+1] - t),x[i],x[i+1])[0]
        
        for k in range(1,M-1):
            supr[k-1] = c*integrate.quad(lambda t:np.sign(t)*(x[k+1]-t),x[k],x[k+1])[0]
            subd[k-1] = -c*integrate.quad(lambda t: np.sign(t)*(t-x[k]),x[k],x[k+1])[0]
        
        C = np.diag(supr,-1) + np.diag(diag,0) +  np.diag(subd,+1)
        return C
    
    
     
    
    a = lambda w: np.real(np.sqrt(w))
    
    M = 100
    x = np.linspace(-L,L,M+1)
    tol = 1e-14
    ts = 1000
    bc = np.array([0,0])
    uold = np.ones(M-1)
    it = 0
    errnrm = 1
    C = Cmatrix(M)
    while (errnrm>tol):
        it+=1
        u = np.linalg.solve(C,-stiffassembly(a(np.r_[bc[0],uold,bc[1]]), M)@uold)
        errnrm = np.linalg.norm(u-uold)
        uold = u.copy()    
        print(errnrm)
    
    
    plt.figure()
    plt.plot(x,np.r_[bc[0],u,bc[1]],'-')
    plt.xlabel('x')
```

Comment: One solution of this problem (with this BC) is $u\equiv 0$. If your code is correct, this fixed -point is not attractive. Maybe there are more solutions, I don't know. The iteration is also not necessarily guaranteed to converge. Have you tried other initial values?

Comment: Yes, but the situation does not change. I think that my post is correct up to the
$$ -M U -B(U) U =0$$

part,right? With Mathematica, they showed that in case the equation is with $\sqrt{u}$ , the problem has a unique solution, so I edited the question changing the equation @cos_theta

Comment: See also https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/questions/230536/steady-state-solution-1d-of-nonlinear-dispersal-equation?noredirect=1&lq=1 for Mathematica solution @cos_theta

Comment: For $\sqrt{u}$ case, the weak form is not correct. It should be$$ \int_{-L}^L \sum_{j} u_j \phi_j(x) \phi_i'(x) \mathrm{sgn}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x + \int_{-L}^L \sqrt{ \sum_k u_k \phi_k(x) } \sum_j u_j \phi_j'(x) \phi_i'(x) \,\mathrm{d}x = 0.$$ In addition, you can try to start the iteration very close to the solution, which you know from the Mathematica.SE thread.

Comment: Thanks! I'm going to try to change the assembly for the matrix corresponding to  $$\int \sqrt{ \sum_k u_k \phi_k } \sum_j u_j \phi_j' \phi_i' dx = 0.
$$ Hope the mistake is there @cos_theta

Comment: @cos_theta I edited my answer with more details, maybe you can spot the error! I assembled the matrix as you described. I checked it's symmetric, but can't find what is wrong

Comment: Without having looked at it in detail: Why is the C matrix multiplied by $h^{-2}$? Shouldn't that be $h^{-1}$?

Comment: @cos_theta  It's correct because, for instance, $C_{i-1,i} = \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \phi_i (x) \Bigl( \frac{-1}{h} \Bigr) \text{Sgn}(x) dx = \frac{-1}{h^2} \int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i}  (x-x_{i-1}) \text{Sgn}(x) dx $

Comment: @cos_theta I edited my answer with more details. If my matrices are correct now, the error must be in how I do the fix-point iteration. I tried several initial guess, but I always get Nan after the first iteration. I begin doubting that my fix point recursion is not right, honestly

Comment: Neither the formulas for $C$ nor $A$ look correct to me. It's not clear to me how you break the formulas up into intervals and then get the results you show.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth For the matrix $C$, I followed the comments of *cos_theta* in the following answer (https://scicomp.stackexchange.com/questions/35955/non-linear-advection-diffusion-with-nondifferetiable-advection-term?noredirect=1&lq=1)

$$\int_{-L}^L \partial_x\left(\mathrm{sgn}(x)\phi_j(x)\right)\phi_i(x)\,\mathrm{d}x=\lim_{a\to 0-}\int_{-L}^a \partial_x \left(\mathrm{sgn}(x)\phi_j(x)\right)\phi_i(x)\,\mathrm{d}x+\lim_{b\to 0+}\int_{b}^L\partial_x\left(\mathrm{sgn}(x)\phi_j(x)\right)\phi_i\,\mathrm{d}x $$

in order to treat the $\text{sign}$ at $=0$

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth While for the matrix $A$, after usual steps, my bilinear form is $$ \int \Bigl( \sum_k \sqrt{u_k \phi_k}  \Bigr) \sum_j u_j \phi_j' \phi_i' dx = 0$$ Now, as you wrote in one of your answers, one has to do some linearizations (like fixed-point iterations,newton's method) in order to solve  the non-linear system, and that is what I tried to do. Since I have the values  of the $k$-th iteration, $u_{k}$, I can compute $A(u_k)$ because the $k$ index runs over (for instance when $i=j$) $\{i-1,i,i+1 \}$ Did I do some mistakes?

Comment: For the matrix $C$, the only way you can make sense of things is by integration by parts. Splitting the integral as you do (excising the singularity) is not correct.

Comment: For $A$, you seem to replace $\sqrt{\sum_k u_k \phi_k}$ by $\sum_k\sqrt{u_k\phi_k}$ but that is just not right.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth For what concerns $C$: I followed the suggestion by cos_theta, because I had no clue about how to treat that case honestly. Should I left it as it was, i.e.  $$\int \frac{\partial }{\partial x}\Bigl(\text{sgn}(x) u \Big) v(x)dx$$ ?

About $A$: you're totally right, thanks. But how can I manage the assembly of that term is the sum is under the square root?

Comment: Well, then cos_theta also doesn't know what they're doing :-) (Sorry, cos_theta ;-) ) I don't understand your question about $A$. You can't assemble the matrix anyway because you don't know $U$ yet. If you knew $U$, you could evaluate the square root of the sum with no greater difficulty than the sum of square roots.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth But since I have a fix-point iteration, I *know* the value from the previous iteration and I can assemble $A$. I mean, I will get to the nonlinear system of equations $$-C U -A(U) U =$$ I decide to use a fixpoint method, i.e. $$CU^{k+1} = -A(U^k) U^k$$, solving at each timestep a linear system with matrix $C$, and, in the r.h.s., the matrix $A(U^k)$ will be updated for every $k$. This could be a way to solve the equation, right?

Comment: Ah, alright. So you know $U^k$. Then what is the problem with assembly? You replace the integral by quadrature, which requires you to evaluate the integrand at individual points. You can easily do that with the square root of the sum.

Comment: Thanks @WolfgangBangerth Meanwhile, I have been able to write the assembly routine for  the matrix $A(U)$. Now I have to write the (constant) matrix $C$: it should be with entries $$(C)_{ij} = \int_{-L}^{L} \partial_x (\text{sgn}(x) \phi_j(x))  \phi_i(x)dx$$ Can you confirm that? If so, I can build it and everything should work

Comment: No, you need to integrate by parts.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth  Okay, so I obtain $$- \int \text{sgn}(x) \phi_j(x) \phi_i' (x) \text{dx}$$ So $C_{ii}=-\int_{x_{i-1}}^{x_i} \text{sgn}(x) \phi_{i} \phi_i'(x)  dx - \int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}} \text{sgn}(x) \phi_{i} \phi_i'(x)  dx = 0 $ and the off-diagonal terms are  $$C_{i,i+1}=-\int_{x_{i}}^{x_{i+1}}  \text{sgn}(x) \phi_{i+1} \phi_i'(x) dx = \frac{1}{2}$$ when the support is positive. It seems to me the same matrix that proposed cos_theta,except for the $1$ in the middle of the main diagonal.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Actually, my matrix $C$ turns out to be singular. I can't understand what I am missing honestly.

Comment: Do you have any theoretical reason to believe that it should not be singular? I'm not surprised at all given that it corresponds to an advection operation that is not well posed by itself. The equation you're trying to solve is only well-posed in combination with the diffusion term.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth Honestly, I have no theoretical reason, but I had two "euristics" motivations:
- - - - -  
1. I was thinking that the term $\partial_x (\sqrt{U} \partial_x)$ should correspond to the "diffusion"
- - - - -
2. This is the steady state of $$\partial_t u = \partial_x (\text{sign}(x) u) + \partial_x (u^2\partial_x u)$$ so I was thinking to set $\partial_t u =0$ and solve this. *This is probably the flaw.*


Just one last thing/check: it turns out that the matrix $C$ is correct now, right? The entry $C_{ij}$ is  $$- \int \text{sgn}(x) \phi_j(x) \phi_i' (x) \text{dx}$$

Comment: Yes, $C$ looks correct to me. The integration by parts yields boundary values, but these are zero.

Comment: @WolfgangBangerth  I didn't know that with that $\partial_x (\sqrt{u} \partial_x)$ yields a ill-posed problem. Thanks for the check

Comment: @Vefhug It's the other term that I think is problematic. It's an advection term with a wind speed $sign(x)$. Visualize this. Think about where information is transported from and transported to.

Answer (score 1):

As the [mathematica.se thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230536) shows, the solution of
$$ \begin{aligned}\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( \operatorname{sign}(x) u(x) \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \sqrt{u(x)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x) \right) &= 0 & &\text{in } \Omega = (-6,6), \\ u &= 0 & &\text{on } \partial \Omega = \{-6,6\} \end{aligned}$$
is not unique. There is one non-trivial solution and the other solution is $u \equiv 0$.

Formulating the equation as
$$ -\frac{\partial}{\partial x}\left( -\operatorname{sign}(x) u(x) \right) + \frac{\partial}{\partial x} \left( \sqrt{u(x)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x) \right) = 0,$$
we see that the velocity of the advection is $-\operatorname{sign}(x)$. That is, mass is always transported towards $x=0$. This also explains the shape of the solution from the [mathematica.se thread](https://mathematica.stackexchange.com/q/230536), which is non-differentiable at $x=0$.

Following the usual steps, we derive the weak form
$$ \lim_{a\nearrow 0} \left[ \operatorname{sign}(a)u(a)v(a) \right] - \lim_{b\searrow 0} \left[ \operatorname{sign}(b)u(b)v(b) \right] -\int_{\Omega} \operatorname{sign}(x) u(x) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x - \int_{\Omega} \sqrt{u(x)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x) \,\mathrm{d}x= 0, $$
which simplifies to
$$ -2u(0)v(0) -\int_{\Omega} \operatorname{sign}(x) u(x) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x - \int_{\Omega} \sqrt{u(x)} \frac{\partial u}{\partial x}(x) \frac{\partial v}{\partial x}(x) \,\mathrm{d}x= 0 $$
provided that $u,v$ are continuous in $x=0$. Taking $u,v \in H^1_0(\Omega)$, this is indeed the case due to Sobolev embedding.

We discretize the space $H^1_0(\Omega)$ by standard hat functions $\varphi_i$ that are placed on an equidistant grid of size $h$. That is, we have $V_h = \operatorname{span}\left\{ \varphi_i : i \in \mathcal{I} \right\} \subset H^1_0(\Omega)$, where $\mathcal{I}$ is some index set.

Using this basis, we construct the matrices $A$ and $B(w)$, where
$$\begin{aligned}
A_{i,j} &= -2\varphi_j(0)\varphi_i(0) -\int_{\Omega} \operatorname{sign}(x) \varphi_j(x) \frac{\partial \varphi_i}{\partial x}(x)\,\mathrm{d}x, \\
B_{i,j}(w) &= - \int_{\Omega} \sqrt{w(x)} \frac{\partial \varphi_j}{\partial x}(x) \frac{\partial \varphi_i}{\partial x}(x) \,\mathrm{d}x.\end{aligned}
$$
Here, the matrix $B$ still depends on some function $w \in V_h$. This gives rise to the (discrete) fixed-point problem
$$A \vec{u} + B(u_h) \vec{u} = \vec{0},$$
where $\vec{u}$ denotes the coordinates of $u_h \in V_h$.

We apply a fixed-point iteration by linearizing the problem as follows:

1. Choose $u_0 \in V_h$ and set $n = 0$.
2. Solve $\displaystyle \left(A + B(u_n)\right) \vec{u}_{n+1} = \vec{0}$ to obtain $\vec{u}_{n+1}$.
3. Check convergence / stopping criterion.
4. If criterion is not satisfied, increase $n$ and go to step 2.

I've quickly hacked this scheme together in the following Python script (it is highly inefficient and doesn't even use sparse matrices). It always converges to $u \equiv 0$, even if started very close to the other solution. One can obtain a non-trivial solution if a non-zero right-hand side is applied (commented out).

```py
#!/usr/bin/env python3

import numpy as np

def simpson(f, a,b):
    eps = np.finfo(float).eps
    # Avoid evaluating directly on the edges of the interval because of discontinuities
    return (b-a-10*eps)/6 * np.dot(np.array([1,4,1]), f(np.array([a+5*eps, (a+b)/2, b-5*eps])))

def hatFun(x, i, grid):
    if i == 0:
        center = grid[i]
        right = grid[i+1]
        return (-(x - center) / (right - center) + 1) * (x > center) * (x <= right)
    elif i == len(grid)-1:
        center = grid[i]
        left = grid[i-1]
        return (x - left) / (center-left) * (x <= center) * (x >= left)
    else:
        center = grid[i]
        left = grid[i-1]
        right = grid[i+1]
        return (x - left) / (center-left) * (x <= center) * (x >= left) + (-(x - center) / (right - center) + 1) * (x > center) * (x <= right)

def hatFunGrad(x, i, grid):
    if i == 0:
        center = grid[i]
        right = grid[i+1]
        return -1 / (right - center) * (x > center) * (x <= right)
    elif i == len(grid)-1:
        center = grid[i]
        left = grid[i-1]
        return 1 / (center-left) * (x <= center) * (x >= left)
    else:
        center = grid[i]
        left = grid[i-1]
        right = grid[i+1]
        return 1 / (center-left) * (x <= center) * (x >= left) - 1 / (right - center) * (x > center) * (x <= right)

def assembleMats(u, grid, intByParts=True):
    A = np.zeros((len(grid)-2, len(grid)-2))
    B = np.zeros((len(grid)-2, len(grid)-2))
    for i in range(1, len(grid)-1): # Test function
        idxRow = i-1
        for j in range(i-1,i+2): # Ansatz function
            if (j == 0) or (j == len(grid)-1):
                # Early out for non-overlapping support
                continue
            idxCol = j-1

            if intByParts:
                if ((grid[i-1] < 0) and (grid[i+1] <= 0)):
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] += simpson(lambda x: hatFun(x, j, grid) * hatFunGrad(x, i, grid), grid[i-1], grid[i])
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] += simpson(lambda x: hatFun(x, j, grid) * hatFunGrad(x, i, grid), grid[i], grid[i+1])
                elif (grid[i-1] >= 0):
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] -= simpson(lambda x: hatFun(x, j, grid) * hatFunGrad(x, i, grid), grid[i-1], grid[i])
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] -= simpson(lambda x: hatFun(x, j, grid) * hatFunGrad(x, i, grid), grid[i], grid[i+1])
                else: # grid[i-1] < 0, grid[i] == 0, grid[i+1] > 0

                    # \int_{-h}^{0} d/dx( sign(x) phi_j ) * phi_i dx
                    #   = [sign * phi_j * phi_i]_{-h}^{0} - \int_{-h}^{0} sign(x) phi_j * dphi_i/dx dx
                    #   = [-phi_j * phi_i]_{-h}^{0} + \int_{-h}^{0} phi_j * dphi_i/dx dx
                    #   = -phi_j(0) * phi_i(0) + \int_{-h}^{0} phi_j * dphi_i/dx dx
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] += simpson(lambda x: hatFun(x, j, grid) * hatFunGrad(x, i, grid), grid[i-1], grid[i]) \
                        -hatFun(0, j, grid) * hatFun(0, i, grid)

                    # \int_{0}^{h} d/dx( sign(x) phi_j ) * phi_i dx
                    #   = [sign * phi_j * phi_i]_{0}^{h} - \int_{0}^{h} sign(x) phi_j * dphi_i/dx dx
                    #   = [phi_j * phi_i]_{0}^{h} - \int_{0}^{h} phi_j * dphi_i/dx dx
                    #   = -phi_j(0) * phi_i(0) - \int_{0}^{h} phi_j * dphi_i/dx dx
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] += -simpson(lambda x: hatFun(x, j, grid) * hatFunGrad(x, i, grid), grid[i], grid[i+1]) \
                        -hatFun(0, j, grid) * hatFun(0, i, grid)
            else:
                if ((grid[i-1] < 0) and (grid[i+1] <= 0)):
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] -= simpson(lambda x: hatFunGrad(x, j, grid) * hatFun(x, i, grid), grid[i-1], grid[i])
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] -= simpson(lambda x: hatFunGrad(x, j, grid) * hatFun(x, i, grid), grid[i], grid[i+1])
                elif (grid[i-1] >= 0):
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] += simpson(lambda x: hatFunGrad(x, j, grid) * hatFun(x, i, grid), grid[i-1], grid[i])
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] += simpson(lambda x: hatFunGrad(x, j, grid) * hatFun(x, i, grid), grid[i], grid[i+1])
                else: # grid[i-1] < 0, grid[i] == 0, grid[i+1] > 0
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] -= simpson(lambda x: hatFunGrad(x, j, grid) * hatFun(x, i, grid), grid[i-1], grid[i])
                    A[idxRow, idxCol] += simpson(lambda x: hatFunGrad(x, j, grid) * hatFun(x, i, grid), grid[i], grid[i+1])

            B[idxRow, idxCol] = simpson(lambda x: np.sqrt( u[i-1] * hatFun(x, i-1, grid) + u[i] * hatFun(x, i, grid) + u[i+1] * hatFun(x, i+1, grid) ) * hatFunGrad(x, i, grid) * hatFunGrad(x, j, grid), grid[i-1], grid[i]) \
                + simpson(lambda x: np.sqrt( u[i-1] * hatFun(x, i-1, grid) + u[i] * hatFun(x, i, grid) + u[i+1] * hatFun(x, i+1, grid) ) * hatFunGrad(x, i, grid) * hatFunGrad(x, j, grid), grid[i], grid[i+1])

    return (A, -B)

def assembleVec(grid, f):
    v = np.zeros((len(grid)-2,))
    for i in range(1, len(grid)-1):
        idxRow = i-1
        v[idxRow] = simpson(lambda x: f(x) * hatFun(x, i, grid), grid[i-1], grid[i])
        v[idxRow] += simpson(lambda x: f(x) * hatFun(x, i, grid), grid[i], grid[i+1])

    return v

def fixedPoint(u0, rhs, grid, intByParts=False):
    nFixPoint = 50
    tol = 1e-10
    for i in range(nFixPoint):
        (A,B) = assembleMats(u0, grid, intByParts=intByParts)

        res = np.dot(A, u0[1:-1]) + np.dot(B, u0[1:-1]) - rhs
        resSq = np.sqrt(np.dot(res,res))
        print('Iter {:2d}: Residual: {:e}'.format(i, resSq))

        if resSq <= tol:
            break

        # Solve inner nodes
        un = np.linalg.solve(A+B, rhs)
        # Add outer nodes (Dirichlet BCs)
        u0 = np.r_[0, un, 0]
    return u0


# Number of points has to be odd (we need 0.0 as grid point)
grid = np.linspace(-6, 6, 11)

# Interpolation of true solution at nodal points
#u0 = np.array([0.0, 0.3600, 1.440, 3.240, 5.760, 9.000, 5.760, 3.240, 1.440, 0.3600, 0.0])

# L2 projection of solution to finite dimensional space
#u0 = np.array([0.0, 0.5040, 1.800, 3.960, 6.984, 9.432, 6.984, 3.960, 1.800, 0.5040, 0.0])

u0 = np.ones(len(grid),)

# Enforce Dirichlet BCs for initial guess
u0[0] = 0.0
u0[-1] = 0.0

# Select right hand side
rhs = np.zeros((len(grid)-2,))
#rhs = assembleVec(grid, lambda x: -np.sqrt(x + 6))

u = fixedPoint(u0, rhs, grid, intByParts=False)
uIBP = fixedPoint(u0, rhs, grid, intByParts=True)

import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
fig = plt.figure()
ax1 = fig.add_subplot(211)
ax1.set_title('Solution')
ax1.plot(grid,u)
ax1.plot(grid,uIBP)
ax1.legend(['W/o IntByParts', 'W/ IntByParts'])

ax2 = fig.add_subplot(212)
ax2.set_title('Difference of solutions')
ax2.plot(grid,u-uIBP)

plt.show()

plt.plot(grid,u)
plt.show()
```

I'd suggest pseudo time stepping (or pseudo-transient continuation) started from a non-zero initial guess in order to compute the other non-trivial solution.

Here's why (please correct me if I'm wrong): Considering the solution as the steady state of the time-dependent equation, we see that the diffusive term (distribution of mass) exactly balances the advective term (transport towards $x=0$). Thus, in the steady state, no mass can enter or exit the system due to the boundary conditions and the flow field. In the transient phase, mass can still enter or exit the system as needed in order to reach the steady state. Therefore, a time stepping based method seems more appropriate to me than fixed-point or some kind of Newton's iteration.

For the fixed-point iteration, I suspect that $A + B(w)$ is always invertible, except for $w \in H^1_0$ being the non-trivial solution. Since we cannot exactly represent this non-trivial solution in $V_h$, we always end up with $u \equiv 0$. Thus, fixed-point iteration is not suitable here.